# Solve Binary Linear System + SAGE

Tags: sage

I have the equation Ax=b where all matrix entries and all entrie of vector b are in GF(2). How I will be able to solve this linear system equation over GF(2) in SAGE software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was answered on the [sage-support](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-support/rIsMum3IONE) mailing list. For completeness, I'll basically cut and paste the answer from there:

```
sage: A = random_matrix(GF(2), 10000, 10000)
sage: A.det()
1
sage: b = random_vector(GF(2), 10000)
sage: x = A \ b
sage: A * x == b
True
```